# NetSuite SuiteScript - print quote with T&Cs

Tags: javascript, xml, var, netsuite

We have a js script that prints quotations within NetSuite. We have created a custom field with Field ID: `custbodytctype` on the quotation that indicates which terms and conditions document should be used (Showroom or Contract). Based on the `custbodytctype` field, we have created an `if/else` statement in the js script to call which text to utilize. However, it currently is only calling the Showroom terms for all quotes so something is not working in the script. Please help!

Here is the original script (that works fine): https://www.dropbox.com/s/pojz0nvdxpy3fqx/printQuote.js

Here is the revise script that only displays the Showroom terms:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/1mer6bngdb056zm/printQuote-new2.js

Answer (score 0):

You need to change this part

```
function printQuote(request, response) {
    var transactionId = request.getParameter('transactionId');
    var tcType = request.getParameter('custbodytctype');   
    var record = nlapiLoadRecord('estimate', transactionId);
    var employee = nlapiLoadRecord('employee', record.getFieldValue('salesrep'));
```

to

```
function printQuote(request, response) {
    var transactionId = request.getParameter('transactionId');
    var record = nlapiLoadRecord('estimate', transactionId);
    var tcType = record.getFieldValue('custbodytctype');   
    var employee = nlapiLoadRecord('employee', record.getFieldValue('salesrep'));
```

This is because you mentioned that the custbodytctype is a custom field on the estimate.  In your current code tcType will always be null or ''.

Comment: I made that change, but the script is still only calling the Showroom terms at the end, regardless of what the custbodytctype is set to.

Comment: And if I switch so getTermsAndConditions section is before getShowroomTermsAndConditions, then I get a XML Parsing Error: Ignoring message when the script tries to run.

See file here: https://www.dropbox.com/s/yycbeijfw9a65q3/printQuote-new3.js

Comment: What is the field type of custbodytctype?

Comment: It is a transaction body field with type= list/record. Currently there are two options in the list (Showroom and Contract)

Comment: Then you need to change the following "var tcType = record.getFieldValue('custbodytctype');" to "var tcType = record.getFieldText('custbodytctype');".  getFieldValue returns the internal id of 'Showroom' and not the text value.

Comment: Thanks Rusty. When custbodytctype=Showroom, the script runs accordingly. However, when custbodytctype=Contract (or is blank), I am still getting the following error: Notice (SuiteScript) Error Parsing XML: ignoring